# Programmatically create drupal user and then store UID of new user

Tags: php, drupal

I am attempting to create a new Drupal 7 user and then assign the UID of that user to a variable. I want to store this UID so that I can create a new node and assign that user as the owner.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone know how to get the UID of the newly created user?

**MY CODE:**

```
        // CREATE USER
        $newUser = array(
          'name' => $refereeUsername,
          'pass' => $refereePassword, 
          'mail' => $refereeEmail,
          'status' => 1,
          'init' => $refereeEmail,
          'roles' => array(
            2 => 'authenticated',
            53 => 'Referer',
          ),
        );    

        user_save($usera, $newUser);

        // MY ATTEMPT TO GET THE NEWLY CREATED USER ID
        $uidn = $usera->uid;

        // CREATE NODE
        $node = new stdClass;
        $node->type = 'referee';
        $node->title = 'Referee report for xx';
        $node->uid = $uidn;
        $node->status = FALSE;
        $node->field_testff['und'][0]['value'] = "testworked";
        node_object_prepare($node);
        node_save($node);
```

Comment: how is the UID called in database or your model? is it actually UID or is it just id?

Answer (score 1):

[`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) returns the user object upon successful save (the variable is sent by value, not by reference). Try this:

```
$account = user_save($newUser);
$uidn = $account->uid;
```

Comment: When I add $account = user_save($newUser); to my code I get the below PHP error.

PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {users} (name, pass, mail, status, init) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => namec [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => test [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => test@gmail.com [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1 [:db_insert_placehold........

Comment: It is also worth noting that this PHP is getting excuted in the rules module.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I used the user_load_by_mail() function. Using the user_save() function caused an integrity constraint violation error in my code.

```
$accountb = user_load_by_mail($email);
$uidn = $accountb->uid;
```

Documentation:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7